# Is it possible to send AWS Redshift logs to BOTH CloudWatch and S3 via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-redshift

We're looking at implementing Redshift via Terraform to our AWS account. Looking at the [Terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/redshift_cluster#logging), you can only choose one `log_destination_type`, either `s3` or `cloudwatch`.

[image: either s3 or cloudwatch options]

**Out of interest, is it possible to send logs to both services?** If so, can it be done via Terraform?

Edit:
Trying to add two `logging` blocks doesn't work, `terraform validate` complains with the following error message:

```
│ Error: Attribute redefined
│ 
│   on redshift.tf line 36, in module "redshift":
│   36:   logging = {
│ 
│ The argument "logging" was already set at redshift.tf:30,3-10. Each argument may be set only once.
```

Comment: Did you try defining more than one `logging` block, one with S3 and one with CloudWatch as destinations?

Comment: Yep! Terraform complains that you can only set it once, will update the question

Comment: Well, then it seems it is not possible to have both.

Comment: That's my thinking, I thought I would ask regardless just in case someone knows something I don't!

Comment: Yeah, VScode shows the maximum is 1 block as well.